# Is it correct to say "I have been leaving the cake uncovered for 2 hours and now it's very stale"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, tense, present-perfect

I think this sentence “**I have been eating for 2 hours and now I am so full**” is not wrong.

Say, now is 12pm and I started leaving the cake uncovered at 10am and the cake was uncovered from 10am until now (12pm)

My question is, can we say similarly for example, "**I have been leaving the cake uncovered for 2 hours and now it's very stale**"?

It seems that some native speakers will say “**I left the cake on the table for two hours and now it's stale**". But if that sentence does not express "**the action that started from a point of time in the past and has continuously progressed to now**".

Is it correct to say "**I have been leaving the cake uncovered for 2 hours and now it's very stale**"?

Comment: Tom, please: to leave the cake uncovered is not an action. It's not like playing the flute. You want to say: I have left the cake uncovered for two hours. Because (I repeat for like the 20th time), you are not emphasizing when in the past this happened but that at the present time, it is TRUE. So, unless you are a professional pie maker, that would not be a sentence a normal mortal would utter.

Comment: @Lambie, so the verb "leave" in this case is just a stative verb right? Even dictionaries don't mention that then how I know. I can only learn though experience. Even you repeated the similar principle 20 times but maybe you mentioned different verbs. I understand the principle quite well but that is not enough because I need to know the usage of each verb specifically as well. And that is why English is hard, you can only learn each word separately not just the whole principle

Comment: This is similar to the use in Indian English of the **present continuous tense** in situations where it is not used in AmE or BrE. For example "I am having a cold". Please see [Indianism of the Week #37 - present continuous tense](http://blogs.intoday.in/businesstoday/Indianism-of-the-Week-37---continuous-tense-62749.html) and I feel sure your English is good enough to have encountered this before.

Comment: Well, Tom, one develops a feeling for these things, but I take your point. :)